# Opening remote PDF with PHP in Google Chrome

Tags: php, apache, pdf, directory

I have a `PHP` script that I want it to loop on each `pdf` file in one of my domain's folder and check if any of them contains a predefined string on it's name, then open it.
I got it working specifying manually the name, but the loop does not work and I can't figure what is wrong.

```
<?php   
    //Value from JS
    $intern = $_GET['intern'];

    //Scan this folder, if a PDF contains on it's name the string saved in the variable $intern, we open it
    $files = scandir('\\\\server\\folder\\folder\\folder\\folderthatcontainspdfs');
    foreach ($files as $file) {
        if (strpos($intern, $file) !== false) {
            $filename = $intern;
            header('Content-type: application/pdf');
            header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="'.$filename.'"');
            header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
            header('Content-Length:'.filesize($file));
            header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
            @readfile($file);
        };
    };
?>
```

I just get a blank content page.

Comment: Why does it require a loop then? You can simply check if file exists on specified directory.

Comment: `};` ?? No semi colon is required on closing curly brackets

Comment: Did you try any debugging? Like a simple `print_r($files);` after the `scandir` call

Comment: Nothing in your logs? Have you tried `@readfile($file);` without the `@`?

Comment: @RiggsFolly It finds the file. (well, it is listed on the result of the print_r)

Comment: @kerbholz Nothing on logs. Yes I tried too, but nothing...

Comment: If I change the order in strpos so it's like strpos($file, $intern) I get an alert telling me that it was an error opening PDF document and this warning in devtools:Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/pdf: "http://ip/path/path/script.php?intern=M-32".